# When did Walter Benjamin say "We collect books in the belief that we are preserving them when in fact it is the books that preserve their collector"?

Tags: quotes, philosophy, reference

In for instance this [source](https://www.quoteswave.com/picture-quotes/407089), it is stated that [Walter Benjamin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Benjamin) once said or wrote the following:

> "We collect books in the belief that we are preserving them when in fact it is the books that preserve their collector."

However, I cannot find the source of this quote. Was it stated in his essay "Unpacking My Library," or perhaps somewhere else?

*Note*: I've also asked this [question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/96460/when-did-walter-benjamin-say-we-collect-books-in-the-belief-that-we-are-preserv) on Philosophy SE - no answers so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would appear that this may be a case of a paraphrase which became more popular and replaced the actual quote in our internet copy and paste, hallmark-quote based consciousness.

Researching online can find the quote used in several books, not just quotation sites.  The first one I looked at was [Hitler's Private Library: The Books That Shaped His Life](https://books.google.com/books?id=pSQSFKeOF5MC&pg=PR15&dq=We%20collect%20books%20in%20the%20belief%20that%20we%20are%20preserving%20them%20when%20in%20fact%20it%20is%20the%20books%20that%20preserve%20their%20collector.&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1pY29wP78AhVkKUQIHdP4DG4Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=We%20collect%20books%20in%20the%20belief%20that%20we%20are%20preserving%20them%20when%20in%20fact%20it%20is%20the%20books%20that%20preserve%20their%20collector.&f=false) by Timothy W. Ryback :

> Benjamin proposed that a private library serves as a permanent and
> credible witness to the character of its creator, leading him to the
> following philosophical conceit: we collect books in the belief that
> we are preserving them when in  fact it is the books that preserve
> their collector. "Not that they come alive in him," Benjamin posited,
> "It is he who lives in them."

Note the quotations only on a certain portion of this text. Unfortunately no citation as to the source here.

Another work also contains your quote, [The Perils of Print Culture: Book, Print and Publishing History in Theory and Practice](https://books.google.com/books?id=SEpvBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22We%20collect%20books%20in%20the%20belief%20that%20we%20are%20preserving%20them%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFuNSL0P78AhUYOEQIHe_rD68Q6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22We%20collect%20books%20in%20the%20belief%20that%20we%20are%20preserving%20them%22&f=false) by Jason McElligott

> Walter Benjamin recognized that we collect books in the belief that we
> are preserving them, when it is actually the books which preserve the
> collector, his mindset, his milieu and the society that he inhabited.

This work actually included a footnote, citing the source, which is, as you suspected,

> 'Unpacking my Library: A talk about Book Collecting', in Walter
> Benjamin, *Illuminations* (Frankfurt am Main, 1955; 1999 edition by
> Pimlico of London).

A version of *Illuminations* can be [borrowed from Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/illuminations0000benj_m9v8/page/69/mode/1up?view=theater&q=preserving), and the only portion of actual text I find therein is that which was directly quoted by the first source. From the final paragraph of the essay (pg. 69, emphasis mine):

> For inside him there are spirits, or at least little genii, which have
> seen to it that for a collector - and I mean a real collector, a
> collector as he ought to be - ownership is the most intimate
> relationship that one can have to objects. ***Not that they come alive
> in him; it is he who lives in them.*** So I have erected one of his
> dwellings, with books as the building stones, before you, and now he
> is going to disappear inside, as is only fitting.

Comment: Worth noting the original publication was likely in German, and I will leave research into that to those more qualified in that language, if they find anything noteworthy to add.

Comment: The German version is available, joined with other texts, on https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/benjamin/kurzpros/chap002.html (search for "Ich packe meine Bibliothek aus"). As a German, I'd call the interpretation of "er selber ist es, der in ihnen wohnt" as "the books that preserve their collector." quite far fetched; I would have expected the German version to use "erhalten" or "bewahren" which just isn't there.